# ERROR unknown command `GEOSEARCH` (redis)

Tags: node.js, redis, wsl-2

I am using redis with node js (npm i redis) and wsl on windows 11, the project I am doing worked on another machine with windows 10 and there were no problems with the command, I recently migrated the project to the new computer and when I want to run the command from geosearch gives me that error (from code and in console), run the example from the redis documentation and I have this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GEOADD Sicily 13.361389 38.115556 "Palermo" 15.087269 37.502669 "Catania"
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> GEOSEARCH Sicily FROMLONLAT 15 37 BYRADIUS 200 km ASC
(error) ERR unknown command `GEOSEARCH`, with args beginning with: `Sicily`, `FROMLONLAT`, `15`, `37`, `BYRADIUS`, `200`, `km`, `ASC`,
```

This is when I call the api that manages redis for me

```
[ErrorReply: ERR unknown command `GEOSEARCH`, with args beginning with: `house`, `FROMLONLAT`, `<lat>`, `<long>`, `BYRADIUS`, `2`, `km`, `COUNT`, `10`, ]
```

I saw other publications where they have problems with geoadd (most of them are due to version problems) but I have not seen with geosearch, perhaps it has to do with the operating systems and that is why I put it at the beginning of this publication. Any idea how to fix it?

127.0.0.1:6379> INFO
#Server
redis_version:6.0.16

npm package redis
redis": "^4.6.10

Answer (score 0):

[GEOSEARCH](https://redis.io/commands/geosearch/) is available since 6.2.0. Your Redis version is 6.0.16